# How to solve having different ranks of tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a tensorflow.js model and I have created dummy input for my model which is:

```
 a=tf.tensor2d([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[8,1],dtype="int32")
```

And I have input it into my model using the following line:

```
model.then(m => m.executeAsync({"input_ids":a,"attention_mask":a,"token_type_ids":a}))
```

Three of the inputs are having the same value, but I am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error in matMul: inputs must have the same rank of at least 2, got ranks 3 and 2
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong and caused there are rank 3 tensors in my input? Thank you.

Comment: You just have to pass tensors with the right shape to your model

Comment: The solution is padding the second sequence:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[8,1,0,0,0,0,0].  And  the attention_mask ::[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0]  zeros to mask padded steps.

Comment: This is really hard to debug without a summary of your model. Try posting model.summary()

Comment: My model requires 2 inputs, having a dimension of 2, datatype of "int32". I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do:

1. Check the input dimension of your model
2. Reshape the input tensor dimension to the expected dimension by the model
3. Then inference